# Deployed react app on cpannel but it shows black white page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cpanel

I build an node and react app that are connected with each other I have deployed both on cPanel but for some reason react app only showing blank white page with react app as title and in console I can see my custom styling but for some reason I cant able to see content
"Screenshot of React App"(https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7MuD.png)

My settings for react app
"Screenshot of react package.json file setting"(https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8dOq.png)
proxy is URL where node app is deployed

Comment: Try to see if there's any error on the browser console.

Comment: As suggested, do you see errors in the console?

Comment: @Haroldo_OK no there is no errors in console

Comment: @Deano no there is no errors in console

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.